# CSS: How to get rid of the extra space of first line of a paragraph?

Tags: html, css

When transforming PSD into CSS, the `line-height` property of the PSD is different from CSS.

In CSS, the `line-height` expand from center of the text, But in Photoshop, the `line-height` is from the top of a line to its next line.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>123436548568</p>
  <p>123436548568</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
div{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

I just want to get rid of this part:

[image]

[Codes in CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hyiDa)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor What does that mean?

Comment: Your `line-height` CSS results the spacing. Just remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [*leading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading) used in Photoshop behaves differently from the [*line-height*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) in CSS. You can use some CSS trickery to produce identical results:

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;       /* this makes the line box is 20px tall */
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* add top and bottom padding to create a gap */
}
```

If the results are off by a few pixels, distribute the 20px padding between top and bottom until you get pixel perfect result.

---

As an alternate solution; offset the paragraph few pixels top so that the top of the text aligns with the top of the box. This solution works even if the text splits on multiple lines.

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative; /* using relative positioning */
    top: -10px;         /* shift few pixels above the normal position */
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kawhr)

Comment: I would add that you should use `margin` rather than `padding` as vertical margins collapse - that allows you to style the space before and after a paragraph without worrying about double spaces between paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, but padding is required for this particular case (e.g. if 2px/18px margins are used, they collapse to 18px while exactly 20px gap is required).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line-height: auto` or remove the `line-height` property

Comment: But I need the line-height property. Here I just exagerate the value to display the extra spacing of the first line

Comment: Can't you use `margin-bottom` to only have space below the element?

Comment: Probably not, Because its about **paragraph**, not about **block**. The margin does not apply to the `line-height` of the each line of the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

reset your css with :

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

**OR**

Use [this to reset](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) default properties for browser

Comment: Really bad practice to use *

Comment: Margins eliminate the outer gaps. The OP needs to remove the gap that is on the inside.

Comment: You would remove all margins and padding for all elements on the page.  This would happen each time you made a request. As Shivan mentioned. This will hit performance @Era

Comment: @Ryan-NealMes : Well accepted your clarification. Keep it in mind onwards. but cant delete this answer as i got rep 10 here ;). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code you could add a class

```
.no-margin { margin: 0; }
```

or

```
p { margin: 0 }
```

But it looks like your line-height is the problem. You need to reduce it. Even after removing the margin your example does not work because the line-height is to big. The first fix is if you want to reduce it further.

Comment: I need to customize the line-height. I here make the line height so big to illustrate the extra space of the first line. I just want to know how to get rid of it. This should have nothing to do with `margin`

Comment: I am not sure on the full context of what you are trying to do, but if you only wanted the first element to have less space you could add div > p:first-child { line-height:20px; } after your p tag style. Obviously edit the height to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The text is that low because you added line-height to it, somehow it's not possible to set a negative margin or padding cause of this.

[image: Selected text]

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` doesn't collapse - every line will be that height, regardless of content before or after, similar to the line height setting in any word processor or DTP.

However, if you use `margin` vertical spaces collapse, so you can use it as the space before and the space after paragraphs.

So the following:

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Will produce:

- 20px font size
- 1.5 line height
- 5px space before the first paragraph
- 10px space after the last paragraph *and* between paragraphs

And also:

- The first margin will be applied before the outer `div`
- The last margin will be applied after the outer `div`